# How to read BDC time with reversed endianess in java?

Tags: java, binary, endianness, bcd

So I have this byte array:

```
// tvltmp[0] = 0x21;
// tvltmp[1] = 0x63;
// tvltmp[2] = 0x84;
```

And this represents `"12:36:48"` in what I called "reversed endianess BDC".

To decode that, one just have to follow this manual:

```
      LSD | MSD 
byte0    2|1    Hour
byte1    6|3    Minute
byte2    8|4    Second

LSD = Least Significant Digit
MSD = Most Significant Digit
```

Which is fair enough.

I just have no clue how to get that done in Java.

Basically, how do I invert the endianess of a byte array (assuming that this is indeed a endianess issue)?

And how do I get the proper values from BCD bytes in java? I mean if I do the typical `& 0xFF` things will obviously go wrong...

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this:

```
public int fromReverseBCD(byte b) {
    return 10 * (b & 0xf) + ((b >>> 4) & 0xf);
}
```